# duplicate entry: android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter.class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-architecture-components, android-paging

RecyclerView 27.1.0 and android.arch.paging 1.0.0-alpha4-1 both contains android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter.class

Does any body know how to exclude ListAdapter.class from paging component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Architecture Components Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/release-notes.html#february_27_2018), you must upgrade to Paging 1.0.0-alpha6 to use Support Library 27.1.0:

> apps using Paging must upgrade to Alpha 6, and Support Library 27.1.0 at the same time

Comment: thank you very much, and I will try to upgrade paging to 1.0.0-alpha6.
Util now, I just specified "force = true" to let gradle use Support Library 26.0.3, and solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this

```
implementation("your dependency"){
    exclude group:'com.android.support' module:'recyclerview-v7'
}
```